# Dismiss UIActionSheet before device rotate?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiactionsheet

In portaint Actionsheet show in tabbar. In landscape - in window. I heed do remove UIActionSheet from tabbar before rotate, for after rotate show in wondow.
Inside `– willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration` dismiss action sheet dont work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use NSNotification for this. Add this notifier in your viewdidload file you willl get notify when orientation is going to change:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
    selector:@selector(OrientationChanged:) 
    name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification"
    object:nil];
```

…add this method:

```
-(void)OrientationChanged
{

}
```

See [NSNotification class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

Me i dismiss before rotation and show after, then the UIActionSheet is replaced at middle;

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [APP.validSave dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:1 animated:NO];
}
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    [APP.validSave showInView:APP.navController.view];
}
```